# C# Attribute access

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that generates a number of custom controls on a form from database values. Part of the program is to store the Unique ID from the database in a custom attribute. I use this to access and change whether a control is enabled or not (based on validation). I can assign values to the attribute and retrieve them from within the class, however when I try to access this in a different class, I simply get the default values.

Attribute class:

```
public class DCAttr : Attribute
{
    int _ControlID;
    ValidationType _ValidationType;

    public DCAttr()
    {
        _ControlID = 0; //Base value
        _ValidationType = ValidationType.NONE;
    }
    public int ControlID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ControlID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ControlID = value;
        }
    }

    public ValidationType ValidationType
    {
        get
        {
            return _ValidationType;
        }
        set
        {
            _ValidationType = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Function that enables the control based on ID stored in attribute:

```
public static void enablecontrolbyID(int ID)
{
    DataCapture2 form = (DataCapture2)Application.OpenForms[0]; //Thank the lord for 1 page applications :D
    foreach (Control cont in form.Controls)
    {
        DCAttr dcattr = (DCAttr)Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(cont.GetType())[0];
        if (dcattr.ControlID == ID)
        {
            cont.Enabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the access specified above, the returned values are 0 for Control ID and ValidationType.None for ValidationType, but these have definitely been changed internally (used breakpoints to confirm, also an internal function is using it and is working correctly).

Any ideas?

EDIT: For clarity on updating the attributes internally.
I access them using a private value within the class the attribute is attached to:

```
private DCAttr dcattr = (DCAttr)Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DCGroupBoxRadio))[0]; // Reference to access Control ID
```

In the initialisation function, I have the following code:

```
public DCGroupBoxRadio(int ID)
    {dcattr.ControlID = ID}
```

Comment: I don't believe you actually asked a question, and I'm not sure what you meant to ask

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on `but these have definitely been changed internally`?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, my brain is crosswired at the moment. So the bottom function isn't working basically, because for each control on the form, the attribute attached to it is returning incorrect values.

Comment: You're looking for attributes on the _type of control_, not the control itself.  Can you show the code where you _apply_ the attributes?

Comment: That class could be like 5 lines of code if you use auto props with initializers.

Comment: See the edit for clarity on how I'm assigning a value to the attribute.

Comment: D Stanley, could you elaborate? If its improper access, how do I get the attribute from the control?

Comment: Attributes are compile-time features associated with *classes*, not *instances*. From the code you've posted, it's not at all clear to me that that's actually what you want here. Do you really mean to say you've got classes adorned with `[DCAttr(ControlID = 5)]` somewhere?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Maybe ive misunderstood how attributes worked. On the classes I simply have [DCAttr()], and then change the value later. I needed a way of accessing a value that each control may or may not have, without casting the control

Comment: Can't you just use something like a `Dictionary<Control, ValidationType>`?

Comment: You cannot "change the value later", and you have indeed misunderstood how attributes work as they're not per-instance. If you want to associate extra data with a control, you'll need to either extend your controls, or maintain a separate store of data (like a `Dictionary<Control, MyAdditionalData>`  static field somewhere).

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that, this is a rewrite of where I did that and it got severely out of hand. Well, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute members are evaluated at compile time and can not be changed at runtime. I think this is the answer to the question you wanted to ask.

EDIT1:

You can change attribute members, but these changes will not persist when you obtain a new instance of the attribute, even if it is from the same attribute type or decorated instance.. which, again, brings us to the answer provided above the edit.

Comment: Christ, that's a pain, completely misunderstood them. Its interesting that they have worked in the way they have then. Thanks anyway. Time to look for an alternative!